# most general unifier of n(a,b) and f(x,y)

Tags: prolog, unification, unify

I know what means unification and I solved most questions but I could't really understand the mean of this questions. how can I unify these two functions. it looks a little weird.

Comment: yes I think so but I'm not very sure so I ask for help. so it can be solved and thanks

Comment: I put it up as an answer so we can close this question.

Comment: The two can not be unified, since if you "peal" both terms, the two functors are different.

Answer (score 1):

If this Prolog notation, you can't unify them. There are only constant symbols and already the root is different, i.e. the functor names are different: `n \= f`